# Is it possible (and correct) to call function that returns array and directly use index key?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible (and is it valid code)?:

```
var x = function(){ return [0, 1, 2, 3];}
console.log(x()[0]);
```

It compiles ok with grunt.. it works in Chrome.. but is it ok for other browsers?

Comment: "but is it ok for other browsers" Um, is it hard to find out yourself?

Comment: Is it ok to call a function that returns data-type `x` and use `x` directly without first assigning it? Yes, but only if that makes sense in the context of your code.

Comment: @epascarello to test (even most browsers.. how much we have? 4.. 10?) and different versions? yes, it is hard. If i was sure if it works just in late Chrome and IE - so it's ok, i would not ask. In php, for example, this feature appeared only in last versions.

Comment: your title say's "is it possible" yet you say "It compiles ok with grunt.. it works in Chrome.."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's possible and perfectly normal.

One could note that most of your array is useless here, though.

Comment: For Jquery it is required to return array sometimes, for example for $.draggable() containment. I need some info from this array, but actually i do need 1 value from array :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason why this would ever fail for any browser.  Your function returns an array, and so there's no reason why you would have to assign it to a variable, rather than use it directly—as in your code sample.

```
var x = function(){ return [0, 1, 2, 3];}
console.log(x()[0]);
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
var x = function(){ return [0, 1, 2, 3];}
var arr = x();
console.log(arr[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

can also do that

```
console.log((function(){return [0, 1, 2, 3];})()[0])
```

or this

```
console.log((function(){return [0, 1, 2, 3][0];})())
```